# What is best path when need change _ID in many documents of CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

*CouchDB 1.1, Windows.*
I reorganize my database from this structure (example)

```
{
    "_id": "0 rock-inorganic 2 m m 10 -50 30 a",
    "inner-coord": [50, 90, 20],
    "map": ...
    ...
}
```

to this

```
{
    "_id": "0 2 rock-inorganic 10 -50 30 a",
    "inner-coord": [50, 90, 20],
    "map": ...
    ...
}
```

Please, suggest simple path to rename '_id' for documents (single / many): Futon don't permit it.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to specify your own `_id`?

Comment: Yes, Dominic. It's fine for my database: effectively search and building view for application.

Answer (score 2):

Save the following view in a design document:

map:

```
function (doc) {
  function isOldDoc() {
    // IT'S AN EXAMPLE: CHANGE IT TO FIT YOUR NEEDS
    return doc._id.match(/^\d \w+ \d \w \w \d+ -?\d+ \d+ \w$/);
  }

  if (isOldDoc()) {
    emit(doc._id, 1);
  }
}
```

This returns all the documents you need to work on.

Write a script to query the view with `include_docs=true` and, for each row, do:

- save a document with the new `_id`
- delete the old document.

Alternatively, you can query [`_all_docs`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#all_docs) and, for each `row.id` in the old format, do a [COPY](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#COPY) with `Destination` set to the new `_id` followed by [DELETE](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#DELETE) of the old `_id`.

Comment: Thank's, Marcello. This sequence I know. Maybe exist **simplest** solution for rename **all** _ID in database (with CURL in command line?).

Comment: @Andrey, you can use COPY then DELETE, as I've outlined in the post. With copy, you don't need to retrieve the whole document.